# How to upload animated webp files?

Tags: assets, volumes

I've created an asset volume to which I can successfully upload jpgs, pngs, static webps etc. But when I try to upload an animated webp I get the alert:

```
Upload failed. The error message was: “The file “example.webp” does not appear to be an image.”
```

The file is an image and I've tried various different animated webps. It seems to just be them specifically. Weirdly, if I copy and paste the same animated webp into a redactor field it displays there and animates and saves fine. Does craft not supported animated webps as a file type or do I maybe need to change something in my config?

[image: screen grab of error message “The file “example.webp” does not appear to be an image.”]

Comment: Go to Utilities->Php Info in the control panel and search for "imagick" and "gd" and see if `webp` is listed in either of their supported formats.

Comment: @BradBell "imagick" was not there but "gd" was and it has "WebP Support: Enabled". I installed imagick just to see if that would work. Its now the default and  has the php info  "ImageMagick supported formats: WEBP" but unfortunately still getting the alert message: "The file “/var/www/html/storage/runtime/temp/p0ly-test-03609d97028efc87.82756094.webp” does not appear to be an image."

Comment: Are there any errors being logged in Craft's `storage/logs` folder when you upload? Maybe memory_limit or max_execution_time related?

Comment: I get two errors logged, neither seem to mention memory_limit or max_execution_time. One is a craft\controllers\AssetsController::actionUpload error saying the file does not appear to be an image. The second is a  craft\errors\ImageException error in the logs. It reads: 
ImagickException: data encoding scheme is not supported `/var/www/html/storage/runtime/temp/P0LY_Test60a2e191a91de2.16978634.webp' @ error/webp.c/ReadWEBPImage/338 in /var/www/html/vendor/pixelandtonic/imagine/src/Imagick/Imagine.php:69

Answer (score 1):

> ImagickException: data encoding scheme is not supported `/var/www/html/storage/runtime/temp/P0LY_Test60a2e191a91de2.16978634.webp' @ error/webp.c/ReadWEBPImage/338 in /var/www/html/vendor/pixelandtonic/imagine/src/Imagick/Imagine.php:69

Based on that error, it definitely seems like an Imagick bug or Imagick configuration issue.

https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/22

https://github.com/gographics/imagick/issues/181

I don't understand most of that (sounds like you might have a webp image that is using some extended features that Imagick doesn't know about), but hopefully it points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Brad, I'll look through these and report back if I discover the issue!

Answer (score 0):

To explicitly outputting a webp image:

```
<source type="image/webp" srcset="{{ asset.getUrl({
    transform: 'myNamedTransform',
    format: 'webp',
}) }}">
```

Comment: Hi Priti, I appreciate this but my problem is occurring before this when I'm trying to upload the file through craft, not outputting it on the frontend. I'll add a screengrab for context.